# Is there a way to add/modify attributes of generators that were created with yield?

Tags: python, generator, yield

So I wanted to make an [arff reader](http://code.google.com/p/arff/source/browse/arff/__init__.py) (similar to csv file format).

And I wanted to use `yield` to make an iterator but also to add attributes to this iterator.

eg:

```
data = arff.reader(my_fname)
print data.relation
for row in data:
    print row
```

but in the reader definition:

```
def reader(fname):
    reader.relation = fname # this is assigned to the function, not the generator
    yield 1
    yield 2
```

Is there a way to do this using yield or am I stuck with the iterator api?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can make it a class.

```
class Reader(object): # Assuming Python <= 2.7
    def __init__(self, fname):
        self.fname = fname

    def __iter__(self):
        yield 1
        yield 2

r = Reader("some file")
print r.fname ## 'some file'
for line in r:
    print line ## 1 then 2
```

Comment: If you call the method `__iter__` instead of `read` you can just do `for line in r:` to iterate over the class.

Comment: @Duncan is correct. That was what I meant by "stuck with the iterator api".

Comment: @Duncan: Hah, I forgot about that. Fixed. I think you are, ubershmekel.